# implementing Google Page Speed recommendations

Tags: performance, google-search-console

When analyzing my various websites pages with [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/), I always have the following recommendations:

- leverage browser caching
- serve static content from a cookie-less domain

I have no idea on how to eliminate or implement these messages. Can this be done:

- through .htaccess
- through php code
- Apache configuration

How can this be done?

Comment: You might want to split this into two questions: “How can I leverage browser caching, as per Google Page Speed’s recommendation?” and “How can I serve static content from a cookie-less domain, as per Google Page Speed’s recommendation?”, as they’re both a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

The [Page Speed project page](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/) has a pretty [detailed information about the recommendations](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/docs/rules_intro.html) including [*Leverage browser caching*](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching) and [*Serve static content from a cookieless domain*](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/docs/request.html#ServeFromCookielessDomain). Read these first and try to understand the problems and proposed solutions.

After that you can implement these recommendations. As you’re using an Apache web server, read [Apache’s Caching Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) and the [documentation to mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html), Apache’s main module for time based [HTTP caching](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). And as for the cookie-less domain, read [Apache’s virtual host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/). With that you can set up a virtual host for your cookieless domain. Then you just need to make sure that your cookies are not valid for that domain (see [*Domain* parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#section-3.2)).

Answer (score 0):

For "serve static content from a cookie-less domain" you can create a subdomain in which you add a .htaccess file containing:

```
Header unset Cookie
Header unset Set-Cookie
```

Comment: Besides that [`Header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#header) is only for response header fields but *Cookie* is a request header field, removing such header fields doesn’t change the fact that the cookies *are* sent by the browser in the first place.

Comment: This is wrong, as Gumbo said. For cookie-less requests, use a whole new domain, i.e. "mysite-static.net".

Comment: @Coronatus: You can use a subdomain and make it cookie-less.

Comment: @Gumbo - That's much more effort, forces you to use `www.`, and means you can't access `www.`'s cookies on another sub-domain, e.g. `secure.`

Comment: @Coronatus: "For cookie-less requests, use a whole new domain". So it is not possible to create cookie-less subdomains?

Comment: @gulbrandr - it is, but then you get the problems mentioned above. Quicker (and cheaper because of the time saved) to use a new domain.